# How to construct GLMM model for repeated measures with binary responses with lmer

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, binary-data, glmm

In my experiment I assigned subjects to one of the 3 treatments A, B or C. Within each treatment, a single subject was tested with two models sequentially. The test sequence was randomized. The subjects' responses were categorized as reaction (1) or no reaction (0). In sum, my data setup was:

- **Subject**: id of the subjects;
- **Treatment**: A, B, or C -- between subject variable;
- **Model**: M or F -- within subject variable;
- **Sequence**: test sequence, which model was tested first -- between subject variable;
- **Response**: 0 or 1 -- binary dependent variable;

I am interested to see if subjects differed in their response between model types, among the treatments, and if there was any interaction between treatment and model. Here is a GLMM model I tentatively constructed:

```
full.glmm <- lmer(Response~Treatment * Model + Sequence + (1|Treatment/Subject), 
                  family=binomial, data=rsp10)
```

I am unsure about the random effect statement, i.e., the `(1|Treatment/Subject)` part. Should any variable go before the "|", and is my nesting structure defined correctly (Subject nested within Treatment)? If not, what's the correct structure?

Comment: Are you only interested in how to accurately reflect the random effects in the function call? If so, this Q would belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), rather than here. Alternatively, if you are interested in the statistical issues involved with GLMMs, nesting, etc., the Q should stay. If the latter, please edit to clarify. If the former, flag your Q & we can migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).